# Oracle Apex two factor authentication

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm working on a project and I need to add a Two Factor Authentication. 
I have my custom login, on one account I have enabled 2fa, tried to do it with with computation after login and leading to corresponding "Home page" (I don't know if this is how it should be done). If somebody can guide me and explain what I'm doing wrong or how should I do this, please I would really appreciate.

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1718/

Comment: Thank you @DanMcGhan . This helped me a lot understanding and I finally built it .

Comment: Happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post given by Dan McGhan is having a great full app that you can follow step by step to have 2FA.

You need to install OraOpenSource oos-utils and then you can download and run the app.