# Get the users Credentials from APEX_WORKSPACE_APEX_USERS for TFA in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

I'm planning to perform a two factor authentication in oracle apex with apex authentication,
here the struggling part is Get the user name and password from the APEX_WORKSPACE_APEX_USERS  and perform the authentication the rest i can do this part any suggestion would appreciate....

Thanks in advance,...….

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what approach you are using. Are you trying to use a custom authentication scheme that leverages APEX workspace accounts?

Several people have posted on this subject (2FA) and provided end-to-end examples of 2FA in APEX over the last couple of years:

- [Oracle Apex two factor authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524083/oracle-apex-two-factor-authentication)
- https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1718/
- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?oh=9281
- https://apexutil.blogspot.com/2018/07/two-factor-authentication-with-apex.html

As far as I can tell, using 2FA generally requires a custom authentication scheme. You can get there indirectly if you reconfigure APEX to use something like HTTP Header authentication rather than username and password. Then user credentials can be supplied by an external certificate or smart card, which qualifies as 2FA. I have written on that subject here: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/category/apex/http-header-authentication/

Comment: Thank you, but i have saw the post, my point here is i want to perform the TFA in Apex authentication, i have the user name but i can't get the user credentials, any idea how can i perform the TFA in Apex authentication.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible. If it would be possible, the functionality would be exposed through an API and it isn't.

Comment: i got it i will find another way